# Javascript: does canvas get refreshed only when <script> ends?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I am writing very basic code hear (just started learning) using Javascript & canvas. I try to do some random drawing (rectangles have 50% chance to appear on certain spots). Once this happens I want browser to wait one second, clear the screen and instantly draw it again (visually one drawing should be instantly replaced by another).

When I do so, it seems like canvas does not want to update, it only updates once when main loop ends, you can find code below:

```
<script>
  let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  function wait(ms) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    console.log("First checkpoint");
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        let width_custom = 60;
        let height_custom = 60;
        let gap = 20;
        let x = 100 + (width_custom + gap) * i;
        let y = 100 + (height_custom + gap) * j;

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, width_custom, height_custom);
        context.stroke();
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.rect(x + 8, y + 8, width_custom - 16, height_custom - 16);
          context.stroke();
        }
      }
    }
    wait(1000); 
    console.log("Second checkpoint");
  }
```

Is there any way to force canvas to refresh **during the loop**?

Best,
Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wait` function goes against the asynchronous nature of javascript. You are blocking the program in a way so things don't get refreshed. You should be using `setTimeout` for this kind of things (or `setInterval` or even better `requestAnimationFrame`).

I have prepared quite confusing but fun example how to loop asynchronously and wait. I'm sure other people will suggest to use `Promise` instead. Or `await` and `async`. It's all good.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

my_loop(3)

function my_loop(k) {
  if (k > 0) {
    one_round(1000, function() {
      my_loop(k - 1)
    })
  }
}

function one_round(delay, foo_then) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      let width_custom = 60;
      let height_custom = 60;
      let gap = 20;
      let x = 100 + (width_custom + gap) * i;
      let y = 100 + (height_custom + gap) * j;
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(x, y, width_custom, height_custom);
      context.stroke();
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x + 8, y + 8, width_custom - 16, height_custom - 16);
        context.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
  setTimeout(foo_then, delay);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```